# How to sync header and column separator lines if scrolled to rightmost position in free jqgrid

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

If jqgrid is scrolled to rightmost position, column separator lines are out of sunc.

To reproduce, make jqgrid wider than browser window or decrease browser window width so that horizontal scrollbar appear and scroll horizontally to rightmost position. 
Header and column separator vertical lines are in different positions.

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have long code. It's not the goal of stackoverflow that somebody debug your code. Could you prepare small demo which reproduce the problem?

I debugged the code and could see that the grid have **no horizontal bar at the initial loading**. Free jqGrid contains detection whether the grid contains horizontal bar *after the data are loaded*. It sets the `padding-right` of hbox (the div which is children of `hdiv` and which have the class `ui-jqgrid-hbox`) to the width of the scroll bar: `bDiv.offsetWidth - bDiv.clientWidth` (see [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.8.0/js/grid.base.js#L825) and [this one](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.8.0/js/grid.base.js#L821) of code).

If you click on Reload grid button of the grid then the problem with the scroll bar will be fixed. So I suppose that you make some changes on the page after the data are loaded. As the result the grid get horizontal scroll bars. jqGrid don't detect the changes and so the problem exist.

What you can do is to call `fixScrollOffsetAndhBoxPadding` method manually *after* you makes the unclear changes on the page which crates horizontal scroll bars. It could be that you just change the width of the grid for example (probably by `$grid.jqGrid('setGridWidth', $('#grid1container').width(), false);`).

What you can do is just to include the call

```js
$grid[0].fixScrollOffsetAndhBoxPadding();
```

somewhere after the scrollbar of the grid will be created. The `fixScrollOffsetAndhBoxPadding` is public and it's the member of DOM of the grid (see [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.8.0/js/grid.base.js#L4233)). The the above code should work.

If I execute the line `$("#grid")[0].fixScrollOffsetAndhBoxPadding();` in the console of debugger I see that the problem will be solved.

Comment: Thank you. Adding `$("#grid")[0].fixScrollOffsetAndhBoxPadding()` at end of window.resize event handler fixes the issue. Is this proper place to add it ?

Comment: @Andrus: Yes, it's exactly the correct place. The main problem is the following: some web browsers, like Google Chrome, use **another size in px of the scroll bar** after zooming. So by changing of Zoom from 100 to 400 one have to adjust the `scrollOffset` and `padding-right` of `hbox`. One see the problem especially clear if `direction: "rtl"` is used. So It's really required to call `$("#grid")[0].fixScrollOffsetAndhBoxPadding()` inside of `window.resize` event handler. I will insert the coll on `fixScrollOffsetAndhBoxPadding()` it the end of `setGridWidth` additionally.

Comment: window.resize calls always `$grid.jqGrid('setGridWidth', $('#grid1container').width(), false)` So `$("#grid")[0].fixScrollOffsetAndhBoxPadding()` can removed from window.resize aftef this change?

Comment: Increasing window size after frozen changes have added in Chrome shows blank area first and after few seconds grid appears. Maybe those changes cause lot of calculations and slow down resizising by adding this ugly visual effect.